# Hide a button in Kendo grid depend on value of column in the grid

Tags: kendo-grid

Try to hide the Copy button in Kendo grid depend the value of status column in the grid in the function gridDataBound(e) {}

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show and hide the button in columns, try the following

```
columns.Bound(c => c).Width(30).ClientTemplate("#if(Processed !='True'){#<button type='button' class=' btn-primary menus' title='Edit' href='\\#' onclick=\"view('#=ID)\"  ><i class='fa fa-edit'></button>#} else {##");
```